# how to shorten grid game in swift

Tags: swift

I am making a grid game in swift where there is a five by five grid of squares and they each are a skspritenode and when the player moves on them they turn to a different color.

This is what i have done so far

```
import SpriteKit




 class GameScene: SKScene {

var alive = Bool()
var targetColors = Array<UIColor>()
var permanent = Array<Bool>()
var has3Colors = Array<Bool>()
var secondColors = Array<UIColor>()
var positions = Array<CGPoint>()
var startColors = Array<UIColor>()
var circle = SKSpriteNode()
var completedSquares = Int()
var started = Bool()
var squares = Array<SKSpriteNode>()
var square1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square6 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square7 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square8 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square9 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square10 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square11 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square12 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square13 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square14 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square15 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square16 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square17 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square18 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square19 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square20 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square21 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square22 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square23 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square24 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var square25 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var basicSize = CGSize()
var columb1 = CGFloat()
var columb2 = CGFloat()
var columb3 = CGFloat()
var columb4 = CGFloat()
var columb5 = CGFloat()
var row1 = CGFloat()
var row2 = CGFloat()
var row3 = CGFloat()
var row4 = CGFloat()
var row5 = CGFloat()
var targetColor = UIColor()
var isPermanent = Bool()
var hasThreeColors = Bool()
var secondColor = UIColor()
var position1 = CGPoint()
var startColor = UIColor()
var square = SKSpriteNode()





override func didMove(to view: SKView) {



}



override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {



    for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if started == false{
            started = true


            start()
            for i in 0 ... 24{

            targetColor = targetColors[i]
            isPermanent = permanent[i]
            hasThreeColors = has3Colors[i]
            secondColor = secondColors[i]
            position1 = positions[i]
            startColor = startColors[i]
            square =  squares[i]


        createSquare(targetColor: targetColor, permanent: isPermanent, has3Colors: hasThreeColors, secondColor: secondColor, position: position1, startColor: startColor, newSquare: square)



            }
            self.addChild(square1)
            self.addChild(square2)
            self.addChild(square3)
            self.addChild(square4)
            self.addChild(square5)
            self.addChild(square6)
            self.addChild(square7)
            self.addChild(square8)
            self.addChild(square9)
            self.addChild(square10)
            self.addChild(square11)
            self.addChild(square12)
            self.addChild(square13)
            self.addChild(square14)
            self.addChild(square15)
            self.addChild(square16)
            self.addChild(square17)
            self.addChild(square18)
            self.addChild(square19)
            self.addChild(square20)
            self.addChild(square21)
            self.addChild(square22)
            self.addChild(square23)
            self.addChild(square24)
            self.addChild(square25)

        }


        circle.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0.2))

    }
}
func createSquare(targetColor: UIColor, permanent: Bool, has3Colors: Bool, secondColor: UIColor, position: CGPoint, startColor:UIColor, newSquare: SKSpriteNode){

    var border = SKSpriteNode()
    var firstTouch = Bool()
    border = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BorderTile")

    newSquare.size = basicSize
    newSquare.position = position
    newSquare.color = startColor

    border.size = newSquare.size
    border.position = newSquare.position
    firstTouch = true
    self.addChild(border)

    if permanent{

    border.color = targetColor



    }else{
        let targetColor1 = targetColor.darker()
        border.color = targetColor1



    }




 func start(){

    basicSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.width / 7, height: self.frame.width / 7)

    createCircle()
    getArrays()


}
func getArrays(){
rowsAndColumbs()
    squares = [square1,square2,square3,square4,square5,square6,square7,square8,square8,square10,square11,square12,square13,square14,square15,square16,square17,square1,square19,square20,square21,square22,square23,square24,square25]

    positions = [CGPoint(x: row1,y:columb1),CGPoint(x: row1,y:columb2),CGPoint(x: row1,y:columb3),CGPoint(x: row1,y:columb4),CGPoint(x: row1,y:columb5),CGPoint(x: row2,y:columb1),CGPoint(x: row2,y:columb2),CGPoint(x: row2,y:columb3),CGPoint(x: row2,y:columb4),CGPoint(x: row2,y:columb5),CGPoint(x: row3,y:columb1),CGPoint(x: row3,y:columb2),CGPoint(x: row3,y:columb3),CGPoint(x: row3,y:columb4),CGPoint(x: row3,y:columb5),CGPoint(x: row4,y:columb1),CGPoint(x: row4,y:columb2),CGPoint(x: row4,y:columb1),CGPoint(x: row4,y:columb1),CGPoint(x: row4,y:columb1),CGPoint(x: row5,y:columb1),CGPoint(x: row5,y:columb2),CGPoint(x: row5,y:columb3),CGPoint(x: row5,y:columb4),CGPoint(x: row5,y:columb5)]

    loadLvl1()

}
func loadLvl1(){

    var targetColors1 = Array<UIColor>()
    var permanent1 = Array<Bool>()
    var has3Colors1 = Array<Bool>()
    var secondColors1 = Array<UIColor>()
    var startColors1 = Array<UIColor>()

    targetColors1 = [.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green]
    permanent1 = [true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true]
    secondColors1 = [.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear]
    has3Colors1 = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]
    startColors1 = [.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue]

    var lvl1Array = Array<Array<Any>>()
    lvl1Array = [targetColors1,permanent1,has3Colors1,secondColors1,startColors1]

    targetColors = lvl1Array[0] as! Array<UIColor>
    permanent = lvl1Array[1] as! Array<Bool>
    has3Colors = lvl1Array[2] as! Array<Bool>
    secondColors = lvl1Array[3] as! Array<UIColor>
    startColors = lvl1Array[4] as! Array<UIColor>





}
func rowsAndColumbs(){

columb1 = CGFloat( basicSize.width * 1.5)
columb2 = CGFloat( basicSize.width * 2.5)
columb3 = CGFloat( basicSize.width * 3.5)
columb4 = CGFloat( basicSize.width * 4.5)
columb5 = CGFloat( basicSize.width * 5.5)

row1 = CGFloat( basicSize.height * 5.5)
row1 = CGFloat( basicSize.height * 4.5)
row1 = CGFloat( basicSize.height * 3.5)
row1 = CGFloat( basicSize.height * 2.5)
row1 = CGFloat( basicSize.height * 1.5)




}
func createCircle(){

    circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
    circle.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width / 7, height: self.frame.width / 7)
    circle .position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
    self.addChild(circle)
    //alive = true

}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {}
    // Called before each frame is rendered

}
```

What i have done is there is a function that uses an array of arrays of values to make the grid but i know there would be a better way to do this and shorten it but i don't know how. I have considered structs but still they would be really long sense i have so any values and i know there is a better way to do this so can someone tell me.

Comment: luckily you have not made a game with a 20 by 20 grid... why do you need actually _all_ 25 pointers one-by-one? if you don't need, why do not you use some iteration to populate your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of arrays that contain 25 items, one for each square.  What you really need is a `class` or `struct` that represents a square that has the properties held by those arrays:

```
class Square {
    var node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
    var startColor = UIColor.blue
    var secondColor = UIColor.clear
    var targetColor = UIColor.green
    var permanent = true
    var has3Colors = false
}

// create the array of squares
var squares = (1...25).map { _ in Square() }

// add the nodes as children of self
squares.forEach { self.addChild($0.node) }
```

You then access each square by index: `square[0]`, `square[1]`, all the way to `square[24]`.

The properties are accessed like `square[0].startColor` and `square[7].has3Colors`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'll just give you one hint. Think about replacing this:

```
var columb1 = CGFloat()
var columb2 = CGFloat()
var columb3 = CGFloat()
var columb4 = CGFloat()
var columb5 = CGFloat()
// ...
columb1 = CGFloat( basicSize.width * 1.5)
columb2 = CGFloat( basicSize.width * 2.5)
columb3 = CGFloat( basicSize.width * 3.5)
columb4 = CGFloat( basicSize.width * 4.5)
columb5 = CGFloat( basicSize.width * 5.5)
```

with this:

```
var columns : [CGFloat] = (1...5).map {basicSize.width * (CGFloat($0) + 0.5)}
```

Do you see the difference? I don't just mean the fact that we've  reduced 10 lines to 1 line. I mean that we completely eliminated `columb1`, `columb2`, and so on — instead, we are using *one* variable, an array, and we're using it *as an array*.

You have a feeling something is wrong, and you're quite right. There is no need for all your intermediate variables with numbers on the end of the name. Throw them all away. An array serves *exactly that purpose*; that is what an array *is* — a name together with a number (the index number) that references one of many values. Use *patterns*, *loops*, and *arrays* for storage; that is what basic programming is.

Comment: This will give you 25 unique `SKSpriteNode`s: `var squares = (1...25).map { _ in SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile") }`

Comment: Well, I replaced the example with something I was more sure of. :) Makes the same point.

Comment: And see my book, which tries to teach you what an array is and how to use it: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_array